# Convert .csv-content to ascii-file to read raster in ArcGIS

Tags: python, r, csv, ascii

I have a ".csv-file" as output of a raster based simulation model. The .csv file contains of three different variables: x y coordinates for location, and a value that should be assigned to this location. What I want is an ".ascii-file" that can be loaded into ArcGIS. Is there any easy way to do this, since I do barely have experience in working with R or Python.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: It would help if you shows us what the "ascii-file" format was supposed to look like.

Comment: You read in data with `read.table`, convert it to a raster using `raster` package and write it to any format you want using `rgdal` package.

Comment: Thanks Roman! It worked fine like this